# Pythonic way of matching string an create a column on a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, function, if-statement, list-comprehension

How can I add/create a column which returns a 1, if the value in the column contains < or << and 0 if it does not, based on a column df['value']?

```
df['INDICATOR'] = [1 if x.str.contains("<|<<") else 0 for x in df['value']]
```

My attempt above returns an attributeError: 'str object has no attrbute 'str'

Answer (score 2):

Create mask and then [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html), [`Series.view`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.view.html) or [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for convert `True/False` to `1/0`:

```
m = df['value'].str.contains("<|<<")
#simplify mask - if contains << then contain <
m = df['value'].str.contains("<")


df['INDICATOR'] = m.astype(int)

df['INDICATOR'] = m.view('i1')

df['INDICATOR'] = np.where(m, 1, 0)
```